# send post with AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, form-post

I want to submit a form in flash and send the user to an other page in html/php and get the post information on that page. How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// create a URLRequest object with the target URL:
var url : String = 'newpage.html';
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

// create a URLVariables object and add all the values you want to send with their identifiers:
var urlVariables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVariables['formfieldId'] = 'formfieldValue';

// add the urlVariables to the urlRequest
urlRequest.data = urlVariables;

// set the method to post (default is GET)
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

// use navigateToURL to send the urlRequest, use '_self' to open in the same window
navigateToURL(urlRequest, '_self');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [URLRequest](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) class